# What desktop environment was Joli OS based on?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, desktop-environment

I know [Joli OS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joli_OS) was based on Ubuntu (or some Ubuntu flavour), but what DE was it based on? Or had it built its very own?

Comment: It used a customized [GNOME DE](http://distrowatch.com/table.php?distribution=jolios)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like it was a custom extension for the [awesome](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Awesome_%28window_manager%29) window manager, judging from the [source code](https://github.com/JoliOS/jolicloud-desktop-environment).

An [article about Jolicloud DE](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2013/04/jolicloud-your-new-favourite-ubuntu-de) also mentions the **awesome** window manager:

> Secondly, the lightweight Awesome Window Manager is used in place of Metacity or Compiz, so traditional keyboard shortcuts or fancy window effects don’t work.